# Best way to deal with a rental car in the Domincan Republic?

Tags: car-rentals, dominican-republic

I'm spending a week in the DR, arriving at and departing from the airport in Santo Domingo. I'm traveling around the country and need to rent a car for the week.

Normally, I would think it best to rent and return the car at the airport. But I'm spending the first two nights of the trip in downtown Santo Domingo and I'm not sure I want to deal with a car there. Driving and especially parking in any old city can be challenging, and [Santo Domingo seems especially known for difficult, scary, and outright dangerous driving](https://www.quora.com/How-bad-is-it-to-drive-in-Santo-Domingo-Dominican-Republic).

So I'm wondering if I should get a ride to the city, spend my two nights, and then pick up a car. But then I'm picking up and returning in two different places, or else having to get back to the airport for pickup, which seems like a hassle.

Can anyone suggest the best way to work this situation?

Comment: I just returned two weeks ago. Personally I’d go with the airport rental. Despite the narrow roads here is on street parking in the colonial zone if that’s where you spend the two nights in that city. The trip from Zona Colonial to the airport is just about $13 with Uber so you can also choose to spend your two nights then go pick up at the airport. Either way you choose.